# Find recently changed cell data and write it into another cell. Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple spreadsheet two columns A,B. Column[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5XH.jpg) B is populated by a (SPC Micrometer) decmil input, the timestamp shows up in column A after the data is input into column B. I need to have a separate cell on the sheet that updates with the last cell change, i.e. the machinist checks a part and it updates the next cell in column B and whatever the last measurement was is reported to a single cell that updates every time a new measurement is taken. I still want a running log of all of the measurements that were taken. I will use the data in the "last measurement cell" to report out to a gage chart on a separate sheet [Gage Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaIwp.jpg).

Any help will be helpful!!

I am using an apps script for the date stamp. I was thinking that the last measurement cell could be looking for a "NOW" cell and report the cell to the right which is the measurement taken at that time, because the B column data is in the spreadsheet before the A column cell is time stamped.

I don't have programming experience, but I have tried to use a script from gethub to look at column B and find a cell change then report the changed cell data to the last measurement cell but unsurprisingly it didn't function correctly. Also posted a similar request for information to the Google Sheets reddit.

Comment: Is column B data entered by user input or script?

Comment: User input. The micrometers connect to the computer via Bluetooth and emulate a keyboard. When the transmit button is pressed on the micrometer it sends the the data on the display to the next cell in column B, immediately afterward the cell to the left (column A) is date stamped. Each subsequent transmission is populated in column B

Comment: OK so nothing is done manually and so onEdit triggers don't fire

Comment: I tried to understand the onEdit capabilities but without any programming background I struggle with what makes most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function dupeSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:ss");//date string for new sheet name
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter((sh => {
    if(!~sh.getName().indexOf('---')) {
      return true;//use sheets that don't have ---
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })).filter(e => e).forEach(sh => {
    let vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();//get data
    let ns = ss.insertSheet(`${sh.getName()} --- ${dts}` );//insert and name new sheet
    ns.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//copy data to new sheet
```

});
}

You can use this to create the trigger or do it manually

```
function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "dupeSheets").length ==0 ) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("dupeSheets").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(23).create();
  }
}
```

Please note I have not actually tested this so some modifications or adjustments may be necessary.

Comment: Reddit replied with this.. =XLOOKUP(MAX(A:A),A:A,A:B,"missing",0,-1)

Comment: It works, Is there an advantage to using the script?

Comment: I don't use anything else so my opinion would be greatly biased.